# Conditional probability of an event given a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

This may look easy but I'm not sure about it. Suppose we have 3 random variables $D$, $Y$ and $Z$ such that $P(D=1|Z) = P(\{Y \le Z\}|Z)$. Let $z$ be in the support of $Z$, is it correct to write : $P(D=1 |Z=z ) =  P(Y \le z)$ ?

Comment: You appear to be asking whether conditional probabilities are irrelevant, because you ask whether you can drop the conditioning on $Z$ from $\Pr(Y\le Z\mid Z).$  Is that really the question you want answered?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Now by reading your question I understand that independence between $Y$ and $Z$ is necessary to drop the conditioning on $Z$.